# How to receive updated variables from other functions?

Tags: python, pygame, return, increment

so in my game here, I'm trying to have a scoring system where every time an enemy is hit, your score goes up by 1. However, the score doesn't seem to be updating and I'm not sure why and how to fix it. If possible, I do not want to use global variables due to my lecturer encouraging us against it.

Here's all relevant code (I have marked where the score variable is mentioned):

main():

```
def main():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("28 Days Later", 35, True, False) # (Font name, Font size, Bold?, Italic?)
    board = player(225, 225, 64, 64, 0)
    DiArrow = enemy(100, 410, 48, 48, 410)
    score = 0 # <------------- SCORE
    bullets = []
    E_bullets = []
    while True:
        moveFunctions(board, DiArrow, bullets, E_bullets, score, font) # <------------- SCORE
```

moveFunctions:

```
def moveFunctions(board, DiArrow, bullets, E_bullets, score, font): # <------------- SCORE
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(15) # Frame rate per second (FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                stopGame()

        fireBullet(board, bullets, DiArrow, score) # <------------- SCORE
        E_fireBullet(board, E_bullets, DiArrow)

        arrowKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        bulletDirection(arrowKeys, board, bullets)
        E_bulletDirection(DiArrow, E_bullets, board)
        playerControls(arrowKeys, board)
        enemyControls(DiArrow, board)
        redrawGameWindow(board, DiArrow, bullets, E_bullets, font, score) # <------------- SCORE
```

fireBullet():

```
def fireBullet(board, bullets, DiArrow, score): # <------------- SCORE
    if board.lastDirection == "left":
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[1] + DiArrow.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > \
                    DiArrow.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > DiArrow.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[0] + \
                        DiArrow.hitbox[2]:
                    DiArrow.getHit()
                    score += 1 # <------------- SCORE
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 50:
                bullet.x += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    elif board.lastDirection == "right":
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[1] + DiArrow.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > \
                    DiArrow.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > DiArrow.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[0] + \
                        DiArrow.hitbox[2]:
                    DiArrow.getHit()
                    score += 1 # <------------- SCORE
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            if bullet.x < 450 and bullet.x > 0:
                bullet.x += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    elif board.lastDirection == "up":
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[1] + DiArrow.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > \
                    DiArrow.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > DiArrow.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[0] + \
                        DiArrow.hitbox[2]:
                    DiArrow.getHit()
                    score += 1 # <------------- SCORE
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            if 500 > bullet.y > 50:
                bullet.y += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    else:
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < DiArrow.hitbox[1] + DiArrow.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + \
                bullet.radius > DiArrow.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > DiArrow.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < \
                    DiArrow.hitbox[0] + DiArrow.hitbox[2]:
                    DiArrow.getHit()
                    score += 1 # <------------- SCORE
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
            if 450 > bullet.y > 0:
                bullet.y += bullet.vel
            else:
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
    # return score <------------------ I tried using return here but to no avail
```

redrawGameWindow():

```
def redrawGameWindow(board, DiArrow, bullets, E_bullets, font, score): # <------------- SCORE
    window.blit(bg, (0,0))
    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (255, 255, 255)) # <------------- SCORE
    window.blit(text, (380, 515))
    board.drawCharacter(window)
    DiArrow.drawEnemy(window)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    for bullet in E_bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I should mention that aside from score, everything is working mostly as they should and that I am using the Pygame module (Although, the issue here is not related to any Pygame functions). Also, board represents the player while DiArrow represents the enemy.

Thank you to anyone who could help shed light on this matter of mine and have a great day to you all

Comment: Can you simplify the `fireBullet` function? There seems to be a ton of repeated code.

Comment: I guess I could try simplifying by putting all repeating code in it's own function, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your attempt to return `score` from a function should work if you do it for every function that uses `score`, but you must also save that returned value from every call to each function that uses it in order to propagate the updated value between function calls. Modify your code to meet the following format and you should achieve the desired behavior.

```py
def functionThatUsesScore(score):
    score += 1
    return score


def functionThatDoesNotUseScore():
    pass


def anotherFunctionThatUsesScore(score):
    score += 2
    return score


def main():
    score = 0
    while True:
        score = functionThatUsesScore(score)
        functionThatDoesNotUseScore()
        score = anotherFunctionThatUsesScore(score)
```

Comment: That did work, thanks! However, now I have run into a different issue. The score is not keeping itself updated constantly for some reason. Like, if the enemy is shot multiple times in a short period, it would sometimes keep itself at the same score, while other times it would update

Comment: The repeating scoreboard result:

`Enemy Got Hit!
1 D
Enemy Got Hit!
1 D
Enemy Got Hit!
1 D
Enemy Got Hit!
1 D
Enemy Got Hit!
1 D
Enemy Got Hit!
2 D
Enemy Got Hit!
3 D
Enemy Got Hit!
4 D
Enemy Got Hit!
5 D
Enemy Got Hit!
6 D
Enemy Got Hit!
7 D
Enemy Got Hit!
7 D
Enemy Got Hit!
7 D
Enemy Got Hit!
7 D
Enemy Got Hit!
8 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D
Enemy Got Hit!
9 D`

Comment: The letters next to the number, D, U, L and R represent the direction the enemy was hit from

Comment: @HaqeemWan First double check that you've handled all occurrences of `score` appropriately. I'm not familiar with `pygame`, but these questions may be helpful: Are there any asynchronous functions at play here? Is there a synchronization mechanism that you can use? Are `pygame.event`'s unique?